# How to print the next weeks days with Rust?

Tags: date, rust

On Ubuntu, if weeks starting with Monday, example:

```
user@builder:~$ date
Fri Oct 30 21:29:16 CET 2020
user@builder:~$ 
user@builder:~$ rustc print-days-of-next-week.rs
user@builder:~$ 
user@builder:~$ ./print-days-of-next-week
===============================
2020-11-02 Monday

===============================
2020-11-03 Tuesday

===============================
2020-11-04 Wednesday

===============================
2020-11-05 Thursday

===============================
2020-11-06 Friday

===============================
2020-11-07 Saturday

===============================
2020-11-08 Sunday

===============================
user@builder:~$
```

How do I print the days of the next week with Rust? (Only manually formatted the output.)

Need it to automate my TODO list, since I always have to manually dig out the days of the next week :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current date, an offset (remaining for next week) `7 - now.weekday().num_days_from_monday() as i64 + day)` can be computed. The rest is just an iteration over the week days.

```
use chrono::Duration;
use chrono::Datelike;
use chrono::Local;

fn main() {
    let now = Local::now();
    for day in 0..7 {
        println!("{}", (now + Duration::days(7 - now.weekday().num_days_from_monday() as i64 + day)).format("%Y-%m-%d %A"));
        println!("=======================");
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=43793200e0d5306c82c6b227868e1121)

Comment: simply wow! thx. trying to start learning Rust. it is very useful!